# ajax html javascript page refresh no flicker issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am trying to refresh the table every second on my HTML page without a flicker. I am using javascript and ajax to try and achieve this.

here is my script

```
var table = $('#dt').DataTable( {
                        ajax: "data.json"
                    } );

                    setInterval( function () {
                        table.ajax.reload();
                    }, 1000 );
```

my table is `id="dt"` and `class="sorttable"` everything i need updated is in a `div="div1"`

I need it to update every second to show new active connections.

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Comment: So what isn't working the way you expect?  What problems are you having?

Comment: hmm thanks for the edit...... I don't see why it was necessary but OK

any ideas on the solution? 

I believe i am missing some code but not sure where to go with it.

Sorry, issues are, div is not refreshing at all. i was just using java-script to do this but want a more seamless way without the whole page refresh

Comment: The edit was to highlight the code elements in your sentence so it's easier for people to comprehend quickly. It should help you get better/quicker answers.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for the knowledge, still new to this.

the script i posted is sat in a '<script></script>' but i think i need to set the 'table.ajax.reload();'

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is not working with your code cos it seems ok to me? The below code should just work fine.

```
var table = $('#dt').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );

setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
}, 1000 );
```

I have added the parameters so that it retains the pagination. Btw I hope you included jQuery library? And I also guess you could also replace `table.ajax.reload` with `$table.fnDraw();` OR `table.fnReloadAjax();` and it should just work equally well

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LKmUxdwg35mHIsyCoMAZ?p=preview) that does what you need. I have set the refresh rate to 3 seconds. Go to any other page so that you can see the refresh in action otherwise you may not be able to see any changes as the data isn't changing .The reload method i think takes parameters so as to retain the pagination. You may want to look at the documentation for that

Comment: Holy Moly i forgot the library. Doing that now, will let you know, thanks!

Comment: OK library is in but still not functioning. 

drawing a blank on this...

still no refresh of table happening.

Comment: The library is loaded before the call is made I guess? If more of the code is posted then it would be easier to figure out.One of the things you could do is to add a button and use the refresh code. If it does refresh then use the same in the setInterval method

Comment: Library is loaded on the master page, i cant post anymore code, everything i have posted is everything i have for this.

Comment: I have added a plunk demo in my answer. The refresh works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set serversid option to true, for serer side processing of datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sunixi=$('#sunixi').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
//reload the datatable after 30 secs
    setInterval(function(){
          sunixi.ajax.reload();//user paging will be reset on reload
     }, 3000);
} );
```

sunixi.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload

Ref: [Datatable server side processing](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)